# SWTException on trying to async(Thread) to display

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, swt

Problem: I need 3 threads. Thread1 reads an int-value and starts an action (that involves a UI) if this value changes. Thread2 is the UI. Thread3 is the action that should be performed when Thread1 notices that the int changed. Now, when I start thread2 and then do

```
    display.async(new Thread1())
```

it won't show the UI since the open()-method is called later. When I do open() first and then display.async() it'll throw an SWTException immediately:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sokobangui.SokobanGUIManager.run(SokobanGUIManager.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Unknown Source)
        at sokobangui.SokobanGUIManager.run(SokobanGUIManager.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

When I start thread1 and thread2 seperately without trying to sync them it works fine until I try to initialize thread3 by using thread2. Then I get this one:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.getShell(Unknown Source)
        at sokobangui.GUICoordinator.switchToRoboControl(GUICoordinator.java:120)
        at sokobangui.GUIListener.run(GUIListener.java:15)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So if I was asked what happened here I'd say there's some problem with sychronizing the threads since as far as I know the display-thread needs to 'know' which threads will modify the surface. However I have no idea how to solve that problem...

Here're some code snippets: (thread1 = GUIListener; thread2 = SokobanGUIManager; thread3 = SwitchToRoboControl)

```
    public class StartSokobanSolver {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GUIStatus.status = GUIStatus.MAIN;

            Thread manager = new Thread(new SokobanGUIManager());
            manager.start();

            //Thread listener = new Thread(new GUIListener());
            //listener.start();
        }
    }

    public class SokobanGUIManager implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            this.display = new Display();
            this.display.asyncExec(new Thread(new GUIListener()));

            this.shell = new Shell(this.display);

            goToMainMenu();

            this.shell.open();

            while (!this.shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
                }
            }
            GUIStatus.status = GUIStatus.END;
        }
    }

    public class GUIListener implements Runnable {
        private static GUICoordinator connector;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                //try{
                    while(GUIStatus.status != GUIStatus.END) {
                        System.out.println("GUI-Status: " + GUIStatus.status);
                        if(GUIStatus.status == GUIStatus.INGAME_ROBOT) {
                            System.out.println("InGameRobot Start");
                            connector.switchToRoboControl();
                            System.out.println("InGameRobot End");
                            GUIStatus.status = GUIStatus.INGAME_SOLVED;
                            connector.isSolved();
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Else");
                            try{ Thread.sleep(5000); } catch(Exception e) {}
                        }
                        if(GUIStatus.status == GUIStatus.END) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                    /*} catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Ende des Threads : " + e.toString());
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    Not in the code atm to get the full exception message!
                }*/
            }
        }

        protected static void setCoordinator(GUICoordinator c) {
            connector = c;
        }
    }

    public class GUICoordinator {
        ...
        protected void switchToRoboControl() {
            if(this.roboControl != null) {
                Solution solution = new Solution("1u:1l:1d"); 
                Thread roco = new Thread(new SwitchToRoboControl(this.map, this,  this.mapArea.getShell(), solution));
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(roco);
                roco.start();
                System.out.println("Thread started");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Epic fail");
            }
        }
    }

    public class SwitchToRoboControl implements Runnable {
        ...

        public SwitchToRoboControl(Map map, GUICoordinator gui, Shell shell, Solution solution) {
            this.map = map;
            this.gui = gui;
            this.shell = shell;
            this.solution = solution;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...action to be performed
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, Thread3 is the one executing action performed when Thread1 discover a state change, right? Maybe some code snippets would explain your use case better. Do you mind sharing them?

Comment: I added some snippets, I hope that helps understanding the issue. But you're right, thread3 (=SwitchToRoboControl) is supposed to execute some action that is supposed to be visible on the UI (moving icons basically), if, and only if, thread1 (=GUIListener) notices a state change.

Comment: Does GUIListener perform any UI actions? I mean actions executed synchronously.

Comment: It doesn't. It only calls connector.switchToRoboControl() which goes into the GUICoordinator.switchToRoboControl() and THAT starts the 3rd thread that performs UI actions (or is supposed to). The GUIListener really just reads the value and calls that method.

Comment: What changes the value of GUIStatus.status to GUIStatus.INGAME_ROBOT?

Comment: If the user chooses 'Solve Riddle by Robot' in a menu the GUIStatus is set to INGAME_ROBOT. He can also choose 'Try to solve riddle myself' and it'll be set to INGAME_MANUAL. In both cases an InGame-view is shown, only that the controls to make the robot move are not visible when he chose to let the riddle be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't start GUIListener at all. Use menu listener for "Solve Riddle by Robot" which will schedule game solving and then perform some UI actions. This can be achieved in two ways:

1) Solving game directly in "Solve Riddle by Robot" listener

2) Starting a thread which computes the solution and then uses "Display.asyncExcec" (or syncExec) to present the solution in the UI

See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/AddSelectionListenertoMenuItem.htm) how to attach a listener to a MenuItem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, that solved the problem so far, but a new one occured: The thread that solves the riddle should update the UI after every step the robot makes - the methods work fine, but for some reason the UI is updated only AFTER the thread terminates and dies, so the icon on the UI 'jumps' to its destination... is there any way to solve this? Because that issue was originally the reason why I started to work with threads, but apparently it didn't help :-/

Comment: If you go with solution 1 then the result is UI being blocked. Use the second solution - start a regular thread (via Thread.start()) and use Display.asyncExcec/syncExcec to update UI from it.

Comment: Wait I think I need to understand this correctly: I do threadSwitchToRoboControl.start(). And within that run() I need to call Display.async(SokobanGUIManager)? So synchronizing the GUI to the Solution and not the other way?

Comment: Nope, I get more SWTExceptions when I do that...: failed to execute runnable;+ invalid thread access: "at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)"

Comment: In the listener create a SolverThread which you should start simply by calling Thread.start(). Then, within that thread each time if you need to update the UI simply pack the update into a Runnable and execute it using Display.asyncExec. You will get "Invalid thread access" each time you try to access UI directly from SolverThread.

Comment: Aaaah okay! Now it's working just as it should! Thank you so much for your time and advice and explanations!